# Unable to Login with Microsoft Account Services in Website razor. stil NOT WORKING

Tags: asp.net, authentication, razor, oauth, asp.net-identity

I just have simple question!

I'm currently stack with my website. I have create a new ASP.NET Website Razor(v3). And I would like to Integrate the Microsoft user authentication to it.
please note: This project is not an MVC project But Razor page Website! In other word: How to add OAuth and openID using Razor Website

**Web Purpose:** Is to allow user to login using their Microsoft Account.

I have the Client ID and the Secret key but still failing.
I first remove the comment RegisterMicrosoftClient Option and I have put my ID and key:

```
 OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterMicrosoftClient(
            clientId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            clientSecret: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
```

and I create 2 Classes:
**1. AuthConfig**

```
public static class AuthConfig
{
    public static void RegisterAuth()
    {
        OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new MyOAuthClient("XXXXXXXXXXXXX", "smS078(*XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"), "MyWebApp", null);
    }
}
```

**2.  MyOAuthClient**

```
public class MyOAuthClient : OAuthClient
    {
        public static readonly ServiceProviderDescription MyServiceDescription = new ServiceProviderDescription
        {
            RequestTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https:sampleapiendpoint", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            UserAuthorizationEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://sampleapiauthorizationendpoint", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            AccessTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://sampleapiaccesstokenendpoint", HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
            TamperProtectionElements = new ITamperProtectionChannelBindingElement[] { new PlaintextSigningBindingElement() }
        };

        public MyOAuthClient(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret) :
            this(consumerKey, consumerSecret, new AuthenticationOnlyCookieOAuthTokenManager())
        {
        }

        public MyOAuthClient(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, IOAuthTokenManager tokenManager) :
            base("dropbox", MyServiceDescription, new SimpleConsumerTokenManager(consumerKey, consumerSecret, tokenManager))
        {
        }

        protected override DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthenticationCore(DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Messages.AuthorizedTokenResponse response)
        {
            //Perform the verification process
            return new AuthenticationResult(true);
        }
    }
```

According to the CodeGuru instruction: [LINK](https://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/implementing-oauth-features-in-asp.net-mvc-4.htm)

Result:

[image]

**Please Anyone Help is much appreciated!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have manage to get the Correct answer of my question.

I had to register my App under Ms Dev app website to get a Client ID and a Root that should do the Trick.

I got the Answer inspired by the following link:

[Integrate App With Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications)

I also rebuilt the Application using ASP.NET Web Application Core 2.0.

And All works Fine Now!

I hope this may Help Someone also!